# Python: AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute '_balance'. Did you mean: 'balance'?

Tags: python

tengo este problema cuando ejecuto el codigo:

```
AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute '_balance'. Did you mean: 'balance'?
```

El codigo que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
class Account:
    def __int__(self):
        self._balance = 0

    @property
    def balance(self):
        return self._balance


def main():
    account = Account()
    print(account)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Estas utilizando el metodo `__int__` y deberías usar el metodo `__init__`.

`__init__` es un método especial que se llama automáticamente cuando se crea una instancia de una clase.

El método `__init__` es responsable de inicializar los atributos de la clase para cada nueva instancia. Independientemente que sean int (integers) o string... no confundas esto.

`__int__` es un metodo para transformar un atributo a entero, (por ejemplo si tienes un 3.4 quieras retornar un 3) pero no es el caso que necesitas.

Así que simplemente declara tu clase asi:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self):
        self._balance = 0
    
    @property
    def balance(self):
        return self._balance
```